# Application Ontime has issue going from 11:55pm to 12:00am - breaks loop - vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro that loops all day from 5:00 pm until 4:00pm the next day. The macro runs 2 loops that each take snapshots of data every 5 minutes. However, i've been noticing an issue when it gets to 11:55pm. At 11:55 it will get stuck in a faster loop and start taking snapshots every second until it gets to 12:00 am and then it resumes its normal behavior. One of the loops last snapshot was 11:53 pm so the next snapshot should be 11:58, but instead it waited until exactly 12:00 am to take the next snapshot and then behaved correctly.

So one loop that took a snapshot at 11:55 and the next one was scheduled for 12:00am starting going bananas and took snapshots every second until midnight.

The other loop that took a snapshot at 11:53 and scheduled the next for 11:58, waited 7 minutes instead of the programmed 5 minutes, and resumed normal activity at midnight.

I'm fairly new to the application.ontime method and not sure if there is something that causes it to bug out when it runs over midnight. Any ideas would be appreciated.

This is one of the loops. It calls "cashHighLow" which at the end points back to "repeatHighLow"

```
Sub repeatHighLow()
Dim spreads As Worksheet
Set spreads = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spreads")
interval = spreads.Range("c127").Value
starttime = Time + TimeValue("00:" & interval & ":00")
stop1 = TimeValue("16:00:00")
stop2 = TimeValue("18:59:00")

If starttime < stop1 Or starttime > stop2 Then Application.OnTime starttime,         "cashHighlow"
```

End Sub

Here is the initial call to start the scheduled loops:

```
Sub runSaves()

datecheck = Weekday(Date)
If datecheck = 6 Or datecheck = 7 Then Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:50:00"), "runSaves"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:23:00"), "repeatFutures"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:55:00"), "repeatHighLow"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:00"), "saveMidFutureClose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:01"), "saveOverNightHighLow"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:02"), "midCashClose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:03"), "saveCashOpen"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:04"), "saveFutureOpen"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:00"), "saveCashHighLow"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:01"), "saveFutureHighLow"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:02"), "saveFutureClose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:03"), "saveCashClose"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:10"), "clearSnaps"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:50:00"), "runSaves"


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wondering about the value assigned to "interval" in repeatHighLow, which uses the value of cell C127 on sheet "Spreads". Is it possible that this cell value gets changed somehow during the course of other timed tasks? Maybe by something that does extra work as midnight approaches? You could try hard-coding the value to see if the problem disappears.

Comment: This is just a user-defined variable that a user can decide how often they want to take snapshots. There are no calculations with this cell or any other references to it so I don't think this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by simply avoiding the midnight time. There is some issue with either the data being pulled in or the way Excel handles going from 23:59:59 to 00:00:00. So I said if the time gets within this window, then just add another minute to skip this data point.